# how to speed up mongoengine queries

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

If I have two objects like:

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    following = ListField(ReferenceField('User'))
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            'following',
        ]
    }

class Media(Document):
    owner = ReferenceField('User')
    url = StringField()
    is_hidden = BooleanField()
    posted_date = Date

    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            'owner',
            'posted_date',
            'is_hidden',
        ]
    }
```

and when I want to look up the following condition where it is not hidden and its owner is someone I am following and it was recently posted, I have a query like this:

```
user = User.objects.first()
Media.objects(Q(owner__in=user.following) &
              Q(is_hidden=False) &
              Q(posted_date__gte=dt.now()-dt.timedelta(days=3))
```

which is not scaling and is becoming much slower.  What can I do to speed up the performance of these types of complex queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `User.objects.get(id=user_id)` instead of `first()`. 
Tough I am not really sure if that will make a difference, I think yes and that is a `find` operation where MongoDB will return a cursor and mongoengine iterates to the first document. Instead, `get()` is doing a `findOne` and returns only 1 document. If I mistake, someone should correct me please.

2) Use a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/) (not multiple single index) since your query is using multiple fields (example [here also](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#indexes)):

```
 meta = {
            'indexes': [
                ('owner', 'posted_date', 'is_hidden',)
            ]
        }
```

3) Limit returning data to only the fields you need, [project your fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-document), using [`only()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.only)

Use [explain()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=explain()#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.explain) on your query to styudy it and improve it in oder to reach a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/query-optimization/#covered-query).

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use mongoengine in production with large documents take a look at this post: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1230

We were using mongoengine but it became really slow for the reason explained in the post above.

We ended up rewriting our whole backend using https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm
That is a relatively new project for the mongodb team. We are using it with Django and it is working much faster than mongoengine with exactly the same database.